# Increasing size of pseudo class

Tags: css

I am using the following code in my CSS, but I want to make it bigger, so it stands out, I tried using width and height, but it won't work.

```
label:before {
    content: '\f096'; /*checkbox unchecked */
    height:50px; /*Doesn't work*/
   width:50px; /*Doesn't work*/
}
```

and how can I find more content code to use it in my content?

Comment: Did you tried `font-size`?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `font-size;`

```
label:before {
content: '\f096'; /*checkbox unchecked */
font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks, where can I get a list of all content code I can use?

Comment: @Nofel Is that Font Awesome? http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome

Comment: @Nofel : Try Fontawesome cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)

Comment: IE doesn't show it correct, it shows funny characters.